# LaTeX dollar signs confuse syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex

I am editing LaTeX code such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\begin{document}

Blah blah Blah blah

\begin{table}\centering
   \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}p{4in}}
   %stopzone
   \toprule
      \textrm{Symbol} & Explanation
   \tabularnewline\midrule
      x & Pronounced ``ex''
   \tabularnewline
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Bleh bleh Bleh bleh

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be caused by `\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}p{4in}}`.
The purpose of the first dollar sign is to put the processing of
column 1 content into math mode.  The purpose of the second dollar
sign is to exit math mode before proceeding to process column 2
content.

The syntax colour seems to be tripping on the dollar signs in
`\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}p{4in}}` and not recognizing the closing
curly braces.  As a result, all text coming afterward is highlighted
purple (image below).  I can't concentrate on my writing.

As per one answer, I tried inserting the `%stopzone` command to
force recognition of the closing of math mode.  For some reason, it
doesn't seem to have any effect.

- Can someone reproduce this lack of effect of `%stopzone`?  That
  might go a long way toward tracking down the problem.
- Is there anything I can do to correct the interpretation of the
  dollar signs by syntax highlighting?  I am using Cygwin's Gvim
  8.2.0486-1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to correct the interpretation of the dollar signs by syntax highlighting?

Out of the box, so far as I know: No. However, you can use the special "TeX comment" `%stopzone` to stop the mathzones. In this particular case, you need multiple comments, so this should work:

```
\begin{table}\centering
   \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}p{4in}}
   %stopzone
   %stopzone
   %stopzone
   \toprule
```

This is *clearly* not perfect, but it does at least partly solve the problem.

Another solution is to install a different syntax plugin for LaTeX. [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) is a filetype and syntax plugin, and it has support for this particular kind of TeX syntax. There may also be other plugins available, but I am not aware of any where this particular issue is resolved.

*Edit: Answer updated according to suggestions from the comments.*

Comment: Wow, VimTeX can actually cope with that syntax? That's really awesome! I'd actually suggest rephrasing the answer and indicating that installing VimTeX solves this issue (and, in any case, it's a great idea for writing TeX/LaTeX using Vim.) I was thinking of this question and I realized another issue here is that the column itself will not be highlighted in math context... In this example, it's only `x`, but with more complex expressions that might be an issue too. I guess that's a limitation even VimTeX can't (or currently won't) fix, correct?

Comment: @Karl Yngve Lervåg: Thanks for point out `%stopzone`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me (2nd picture posted at the end of the question). I will carefully mull over VimTeX. Getting spun up on a whole new way of doing things is not something to be taken lightly at this point (in fact, isn't feasible for me at this point).

Comment: I found that I can get away with using three separate consecutive lines of `%stopzone`.  Having them on one line like `%stopzone %stopzone %stopzone` doesn't work.  Having a space after the `%` symbol doesn't work.  As you said, it's not ideal, but it will work in a pinch.  Can you please update your answer with this detail?  Thanks!

Comment: I've rephrased the answer as suggested in the comments. OP: You should know that it is possible to use VimTeX pretty much as a plug-and-play plugin. It should not cost you much time if you don't want to spend time learning the various features.

@filbranden Yes, you're right that the columns should preferably be highlighted in math mode, but capturing that seems way too difficult to parse.

Comment: @Karl Yngve Lervåg: Thanks.  I will keep it in mind.  It never hurts to have another Vim capability up one's sleeve.